# MUI Date Calendar Dynamic data how do I set value replace default value?

Tags: material-ui, react-tsx, mui-x-date-picker

[image: I want to custom MUI DateCalendar and I want on my day but now this image show value on calendar still default(random value) I try to change be my value. Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks!]

[MUI DateCalendar Dynamic data](https://codesandbox.io/s/qrrmhx?file=/Demo.tsx)

I want to add holidays and use holidays.date

```
interface NoticeCalendar {
        date?: string | number | Dayjs | Date | null | undefined;
        description: string;
    }

const [holidays, setHolidays] = useState<NoticeCalendar[]>([]);
```

assume

```
holidays: [
{ date: "08 Sep 2023", description: "holiday1" },
{ date: "14 Sep 2023", description: "holiday2" },
{ date: "22 Sep 2023", description: "holiday3" },
{ date: "12 Oct 2023", description: "holiday3" },
]
```